# Trying to draw benzene triozonide using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am new to latex. I was trying to draw benzene triozonide using chemfig but can't figure out how to do so. I tried `\chemfig{*6(CH-(-[5]O-[7]O-)(-[7]O-)CH-CH(-[0]O-[2]O-)(-O-)CH-CH(-[3]O-[5]O-)(-O-)CH-)}` its not working. here's an image what I want to draw.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an "atom-by-atom" solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
        HC?[cc](-[:-120,1,2]O?[oa])-[:-30,1]O-[:-30,1]CH(-[:-120,1,1]O?[oa])
        -[:30,2,1]CH(-[,1]O?[ob])-[2,1]O-[2,1]CH(-[,1]O?[ob])
        -[:150,2,1,1]CH(-[:120,1,1]O?[oc])-[:210,1]O-[:210,1,1,2]HC?[cc](-[:120,1,2]O?[oc])
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\def\0{\phantom{C}}
\definesubmol\x1{-[::-30,,#1]O-[::90,2]O-[::90]\0}
\chemfig[bond offset=4pt]{\0-[::-90,2]CH(!\x1)-[::60,,1]O-[::0]CH-[::60,2,1]CH(!\x2)-[::60,,1]O-[::0]CH-[::60,2,,1]CH(!\x1)-[::60,,1]O-[::0,,,1]CH}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It would be good to add some explanation of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works !

Answer (score 2):

My first time with chemfig -- like all trees its a pain to punch in angles

This is not a complete solution but maybe points you in the right direction -- the last connecting O to CH needs correction and the O midway in the bonds needs to be understood -- thereafter easy to replicate

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{CH*6(-CH(-[::-90]O(-[::-90]O(O)-[::270]))-CH-CH-CH-CH-[,,2,2])}
\end{document}
```